# css3 media queries not working in firefox and opera

Tags: css

I have written some media queries for ipad landscape and portrait. But when I am checking how the media queries are functioning by changing body background color in different browsers, nothing happening in firefox and opera. Could anybody can tell me a solution for this.???

Comment: My crystal ball isn't working today, can you show us your relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add spaces between the @media screen 'and () and ()'. Then it works for me.

So:

**YES:**

```
@media screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px) { }
```

**NO:**

```
@media screen and(min-width:769px)and(max-width:1024px) { }
```

Comment: And how do you know this is the answer to the OP's question?

Comment: There was a comment that included the link to jsfiddle which was removed since it did not answer the question :) See: http://jsfiddle.net/eChwK/4/ (edited version)